# Crear un array al iterar las filas de una tabla de pandas con condiciones

Tags: python, array, pandas, numpy, condiciones

Estoy creando una tabla con pandas donde las dos primeras columnas son creadas con numpy arrays:

```
age = np.random.randint(20,85,size=400)

possible_genders = ['male','female']
gender =  [np.random.choice(possible_genders) for i in range(400)]
```

la tabla en si es:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age': age, 'gender': gender})
```

Entonces quiero crear una tercera columna que sea otro array cuyos valores estén en función de varoles *age* y *gender* de la siguiente forma:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
if gender == 'male' and age > 45:
    print(1)
elif gender == 'male' and age < 45:
    print(2)
elif gender == 'female' and age > 55:
    print(3)
else:
    print(4)
```

De momento sólo he puesto los prints para testear si discrimina cada caso bien en relación a la tabla original pero el output que generan los prints es una columna de 400 cuatros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué se debe? ¿Cómo puedo conseguir esta discriminación de forma efectiva?

Comment: ¿No sería `if row.gender`  y `row.age` en vez de `if gender` y `age`? Entiendo que `gender` y `age` son otras variables que no tienen nada qué ver (son las listas que usaste al principio para crear el dataframe ¿no?)

Comment: Sí, eso es! Si respondes te pongo el tic verde abulafia. O cómo hago? edito la pregunta con la respuesta y te cito??

Comment: Puedes responderte a tí mismo, mejor eso que editar la pregunta para poner una respuesta. Y de paso completas la respuesta y pones cómo has creado la columna extra en vez de hacer los `print`. Incluso puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta si no aparecen otras pasado un tiempo. Cuidado con la indentación al pegar código. Mira esto: https://bit.ly/SOesPASTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como abulafia decía hay que especificar `row.gender` y `row.age` para luego con la función `choiceChol()` asignar un valor de colesterol en un rango determinado según género y edad:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.gender == 'male' and row.age > 45:
        choiceChol(159, 200)  
    elif row.gender == 'male' and row.age < 45:
        choiceChol(75, 150)
    elif row.gender == 'female' and row.age > 55:
        choiceChol(159, 200)
    else:
        choiceChol(75, 150)
```